# Pulling a video file from TextureView To Be saved

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

Currently, I'm building a camera app using camera2 api. I record the video and that file is sent to another activity to make sure we can correct orientation and watch the video. Then the altered video or picture is saved to the device.

When I use a still image it works, because I can pull the bitmap image and then resave the image like this:

```
 public String saveImage() {

    //Getting a new file name and file path
    //Should we delete these images after were done with them?
    File newImageFile = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File newImageFolder = new File(newImageFile, "camera2VideoImage");
    if (newImageFolder.exists())
    {
        newImageFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "Image_" + timestamp + "_";
    File imageFile = null;
    try {
        imageFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", newImageFolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String newFileName = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();


    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();


    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //returning the new file path.
    return newFileName;
}
```

This works, they view the image and have the option to change orientation on the image in case it is messed up and then we resave.

I'm trying to do the same with a video, but not sure how to pull the video from the textureView so I can save again with the corrected orientation as the front facing camera is upside down sometimes depending on the phone.

The recording save method:

```
 public String saveVideo() {

    //Getting a new file name and file path
    //Should we delete these images after were done with them?
    File newVideoFile = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    File newVideoFolder = new File(newVideoFile, "camera2VideoImage");
    if (newVideoFolder.exists())
    {
        newVideoFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String prepend = "Video_" + timestamp + "_";
    File videoFile = null;
    try {
        videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".jpg", newVideoFolder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String newFileName = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();


    textureView.getBitmap();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

    //returning the new file path.
    return newFileName;
}
```

How do I get the corrected video from the texture view and then save it, like the Image method above?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended way; the cost of getBitmap on TextureView is high, and not likely suitable for 30fps video recording.

But if you really want to try, you need to feed the Bitmap to a [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html?hl=en); you may be able to use MediaRecorder.getSurface() for that, then lock the Surface Canvas and draw your Bitmap into it.

However, I would not be surprised if the performance is poor, or if the MediaRecorder Surface won't accept RGB Bitmaps.

In general, you want to connect the camera API directly to the MediaRecorder or MediaCodec Surface.  If you really need to edit frames in the middle, using the GPU is generally the most performant option, though it's a lot of code to write to do that.

Comment: I do use media recorder to record the initial video, the problem is the orientation is upside down when you use the front-facing camera horizontally. Don't seem to be any way to correct it, as the preview when recording looks fine, but when you open it, it is upside down.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the configuration on the Media Recorder, looks like I was trying to correct other orientation problems and caused this. So under my set up mediaRecorder I did this:

```
 private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(100000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(),mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    if (cameraCheck.contains("1") && mTotalRotation == 180){
        //This corrects problems for the front facing camera when recording, the default settings work, so we do nothing here.
    }else {

       mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
    }


    mMediaRecorder.prepare();


}
```

This checks if it is the front-facing camera and the phone is positioned at 180. If it is do nothing for correction, else use the correction.